# keeping file across android app uninstall/reinstall

Tags: android, android-ndk, scoped-storage

I maintain a native app that has a thin Android layer. This app relies on a data file that has been in `/sdcard`, however starting with Android 11 [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) will be enforced, so `/sdcard` will either no longer be available or be scoped to the app if i understand correctly. So i migrated the file onto `.` (so it now resides in the `files/` directory of the app).

However, if the user decides to uninstall and then reinstall the app (which may be done as a quasi-upgrade process) the `files/` directory is erased and so is the data file.

Both [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) and [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) are deprecated in API 29, the latter of which seemed to serve my needs.

So where can i put a file that will survive an uninstall if targeting Android 11?

This should be accessible through JNI in native code.

[getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) states that *these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled* so that's a no. Intents and MediaStore are also out since this is a native app.

---

After some experimenting, `getStorageDirectory` maps to `/storage`, which is owned by root, i'm not sure i could write there.

`getDataDirectory` maps to `/data`, owned by system, can't even list it, must have one of those com.my.app/0 subdirectory structures, so liable for deletion.

The <del>deprecated</del> `getExternalStorageDirectory` maps to `/storage/emulated/0`, which is `/sdcard`, so it may be a candidate so long as i keep using `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`. I hope. While i assume contents won't be deleted, i'm unsure if `/sdcard` will be accessible, although i'd assume `getExternalStorageDirectory` will, <del>if not deprecated</del>, even if pointing to the same location.
Oddly enough my test device is an Android 10 with API 29 and uses `getExternalStorageDirectory` just fine, but maybe that's because i'm targeting lower?

I'm trying to figure out how to pass `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` onto the JNI call of `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, a bit unsuccessfully, and it's also flagged as deprecated.

Comment: Every app has two 'files' directories so better give full path.

Comment: You can safely use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() for Documents directory. Its not deprecated anymore.

Comment: So use a subfolder in that public Document's directory. Files in them will survive uninstall. At reinstall your app has no access to those files anymore. Unless you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose your subfolder.

Comment: @blackapps source for that? It's marked deprecated in the docs.

Comment: @blackapps the Android 12 [diff report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/32/changes) states `getExternalStorageDirectory` is no longer deprecated, answer it if you want.

Comment: What do you want to hear? And use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is [no longer deprecated](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/32/changes) i'm using that instead of hardcoded `/sdcard`.

`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)` keeps returning the same as `getExternalStorageDirectory()` + whichever string i pass it, which makes it rather useless.